# Create two nonce in one transaction for Square payment gateway

Tags: php, square

I am working on Square payment gateway and I created three steps creating a customer, creating a card, and then making a payment.

```
            $create_customer_request = new \Square\Models\CreateCustomerRequest();
            $address = new \Square\Models\Address();
            $address->setAddressLine1($ship_address);
            $address->setPostalCode($_POST['ship_postcode']);
            $address->setCountry('US');
            $create_customer_request->setGivenName($_POST['f_name']);
            $create_customer_request->setFamilyName($_POST['f_name']);
            $create_customer_request->setEmailAddress($_POST['email']);
            $create_customer_request->setAddress($address);
            $create_customer_request->setPhoneNumber($_POST['phone']);
            $create_customer_request->setReferenceId($_POST['f_name']."-customer-".rand(10,15));
            $create_customer_request->setNote('A customer');
            $custcreateapiResponse = $client->getCustomersApi() >createCustomer($create_customer_request);
            $custcreateapiResponse->isSuccess();
            $_SESSION['temp_customer_id'] = $cust_res->getCustomer()->getId();
```

creating a card request

```
$body_card = new \Square\Models\CreateCustomerCardRequest($_POST['nonce']);
$card_api_response = $client->getCustomersApi()->createCustomerCard($_SESSION['temp_customer_id'], $body_card);
```

making a payment

```
$payments_api = $client->getPaymentsApi();
$money->setAmount(10);
$money->setCurrency('USD');
$pay_body = new \Square\Models\CreatePaymentRequest($_POST['nonce'],uniqid(),$money);
$pay_body->setCustomerId($_SESSION['temp_customer_id']);
$response = $client->getPaymentsApi()->createPayment($pay_body);
```

The issue I am having right now, I need to make two requests with the Nonce token but the system doesn't allow me to do it for the Square payment gateway. Don't know what to do now, Any kind of help will be appreciated. Pardon me for any mistakes here.

Comment: "Doesn't allow me"? what happens when you do?

Comment: @ArSeN "Card nonce already used with a different idempotency key; please request a new nonce." I am getting this error message when I use the second time the same nonce token

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried many solutions from the internet but none of them work for me, so I try logic by myself. I know it's not a good approach, however, it works for me

in payment form, I create another hidden field

```
<input type="hidden" id="card-nonce-1" name="nonce1">
```

create a new function in sq-payment-form.js

```
function onGetCardNoncesecond(event) {
 event.preventDefault();
 paymentForm.requestCardNonce();
}
```

and put the value in a hidden field and submit and use it. Any suggestion would be appreciated for the betterment.